# PHP OOP Singleton Class

Tags: php, oop, singleton

I have the code

```
public static function constructMe() {
    if(!$this->_instance instanceof self) {
    $this->_instance = new self();
    }
    return $this->_instance;
}
```

To instansiate the class, and there is a `$_instance` variable in the class, but I'm getting the error:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use

```
self::$_instance
```

Since you're in a static scope (you have no `$this`)

Also, make sure you declare

```
private static $_instance;
```

Also, I don't know if `new self();` works
You could try `new __CLASS__()` or just write the name of the class ..

And don't use an `instanceof`, just check with `isset` or `empty` (it's more accurate)

And be careful using `!$var instanceof something`, always write as `!($var instanceof something)` because you don't want to accidentally cast to a boolean.

Comment: Yes you can do `new self();`.

Comment: Yeah, but if it's equal to "cake" or something, then you know.. It just seems safer to use instanceof.

Comment: If it's being set to "cake" you have bigger problems ;)

Comment: Hm, cake hasn't been a problem in the past ;) haha

Comment: @Frits what do you mean by `.. dont use an instanceof .. it's more accurate`?

Comment: Well, since you're using the singleton pattern. The value of `$_instance` is either undefined or an object of the class. `isset` seems like the most logical way to check because `instanceof` will fail when it's anything but an instance of the class. I guess you could argue `instanceof` is more correct but it suggests `$_instance` can also be an object of a different class, which is weird. With `isset` you're saying: either it's there and it's fine, or it's not there and I need to create it.

Comment: In languages like Java and C++ where you have static typing you would just check for null, likely because it's faster than an instanceof check. I don't know the performance characteristics in PHP but you can expect them to be similar.

Comment: `if (!self::$instance) self::$instance = new self();` sufficiently solves the problem.

Comment: Yes, and it would also get you fired if you were one my colleagues ;)

Comment: @Frits - Once you've already thrown in the towel and decided to use the singleton pattern, all bets are off. :) However, `if (!self::$_instance)` is perfectly acceptable. Since `$_instance` is private (it better be), it can only be `null` or an instance of the class. If you write code that allows it to be anything other, only then would I support a career change.

Comment: Thankyou for all the advice. Very helpful.

Comment: @David very true :D Initially `$_instance` will be undefined though, not `null`. If it were `null` I would check with `is_null()`. I don't like type coercion, `!` implies you're dealing with a `boolean`. `isset` is just so much stricter than `!`

Comment: @Frits - I struggled at first with PHP's various type coercions that seemed less strict than Java, C, etc. But as I got more comfortable with them I came to trust them. `!` on an object reference is always `true` and `false` for `null`. In the code where I use this pattern I initialize `$_instance` to `null`, but IIRC even undefined will evaluate to `false` here.

Comment: In that case I would recommend `is_null`